# An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class could not be converted to string")

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

this is my controller

```
 public function personnePhysiqueDetailsAction($id)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $controle = $this->get('Controles');
        if(($controle->is_Granted('Afficher détail client','Client/Societaire',$this->getUser()))==false){throw new AccessDeniedException();}
//        $listePersonnePhysiques=$personnePhysique = $em->getRepository('ITBundle:PersonnePhysique')->findAll();
        $personnePhysique = $em->getRepository('ITBundle:PersonnePhysique')->find($id);
        $adresses=$em->getRepository('ITBundle:Adresse')->findOneBy(array('personne'=>$personnePhysique));
        $mails=$em->getRepository('ITBundle:Email')->findOneBy(array('personne'=>$personnePhysique));
        $telephones=$em->getRepository('ITBundle:Telecom')->findBy(array('personne'=>$personnePhysique));
        $contrat=$em->getRepository('ITBundle:Contrat')->findBy(array('souscripteur'=>$personnePhysique));
        $branches = $em->getRepository('ITBundle:Branche')->findAll();
        $compteBancaire=$em->getRepository('ITBundle:CompteBancaire')->findBy(array('personne'=>$personnePhysique));
        $avenants=$em->getRepository('ITBundle:AvenantSignaletique')->findBy(array('personne'=>$personnePhysique));
        $adresseHisto=$em->getRepository('ITBundle:AdresseHisto')->findBy(array('avenant'=>$avenants));
        $compteHisto=$em->getRepository('ITBundle:CompteBancaireHisto')->findBy(array('avenant'=>$avenants));
        $personnephysiquehisto=$em->getRepository('ITBundle:PersonnePhysiqueHisto')->findBy(array('avenant'=>$avenants));
        $familles=$em->getRepository('ITBundle:Famille')->findBy(array('personne'=>$personnePhysique));
```

and thid is my repository

```
public function PersonnePhysiqueDetail($id){
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
            ->select(' p.id, p.nom , p.prenom, p.cin, p.dateNaissance,p.sexe, s.libelle situation,s.id idSituation')
            ->innerJoin('p.situationFamiliale', 's')
            ->where('p.id = :idPersonne')
            ->setParameter('idPersonne', $id)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
    }
```

in my twig

```
{% for famille in familles %}
                                            <tr>

                                                <th>{{ famille.personne }}:</th>


                                            </tr>
                                            {% endfor %}
```

this is the declation of familles in my entity personne

```
/**
     * @var array
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="IT\ITBundle\Entity\Famille",cascade={"persist","remove"}, mappedBy="personne")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="enfant_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $familles;
 /**
     * Add famille
     *
     * @param \IT\ITBundle\Entity\Famille $famille
     *
     * @return Personne
     */
    public function addFamille(\IT\ITBundle\Entity\Famille $famille)
    {
        $this->familles[] = $famille;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove famille
     *
     * @param \IT\ITBundle\Entity\Famille $famille
     */
    public function removefamille(\IT\ITBundle\Entity\Famille $famille)
    {
        $this->familles->removeElement($famille);
    }

    /**
     * Get familles
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getfamilles()
    {
        return $this->familles;
    }
```

and my famille entity is

```
<?php

namespace IT\ITBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Famille
 * @ORM\Table(name="famille")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="IT\ITBundle\Repository\FamilleRepository")

 */

class Famille
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="lien", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $lien;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="IT\ITBundle\Entity\Personne", inversedBy="familles")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="personne_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * #var array
     * #ORM\Column(name="personne_id", type="array")
     */

    private $personne;
    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="IT\ITBundle\Entity\Personne", inversedBy="familles")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="enfant_id", referencedColumnName="id")

     */
    private $enfant;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set lien
     *
     * @param string $lien
     * @return Famille
     */
    public function setLien($lien)
    {
        $this->lien = $lien;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get lien
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLien()
    {
        return $this->lien;
    }

    /**
     * Set personne
     *
     * @param \IT\ITBundle\Entity\Personne $personne
     *
     * @return Personne
     */
    public function setPersonne(\IT\ITBundle\Entity\Personne $personne = null)
    {
        $this->personne = $personne;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get personne
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
     */
    public function getPersonne()
    {
        return $this->personne;
    }

    /**
     * Set enfant
     *
     * @param \IT\ITBundle\Entity\Famille $enfant
     *
     * @return Personne
     */
    public function setEnfant($enfant)
    {
        $this->enfant = $enfant;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get enfant
     *
     * @return Personne
     */
    public function getEnfant()
    {
        return $this->enfant;
    }
    public function __construct()
    {

        $this->familles = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();

    }
}
```

i know that personne is a array thats makes the problem 
now i wanna your syggestion please how can i show in my twig 'personne_nom' where id(in personne)= enfant_id(in famille)

Comment: personne is not an array, that s an object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show Personne information, you have to do this

```
{% for famille in familles %}
   <tr>
     <th>{{ famille.personne.name }} :</th>
   </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

I wrote name, supposing your personne entity has a name because you didn't show us the full personne entity, but put what you need

Comment: thinks t-n-y for your help but in this case it show me only the name of personne that im consulting but for me i wana get the name of personne with relation with personne in famille  (when id(Personn entity) = personne_id (Famille entity hope that u understund my bad english

Comment: i don't understand

Comment: thinks again t-n-y it works with ur methode i hade just change <th>{{ famille.personne.name }} :</th>   by<th>{{ famille.enfant.name }} :</th>

Comment: great if it works, don't forget to put the answer as resolved so

Answer (score 0):

with the same entityes and controller code i wanna get teh invers of

```
{% for famille in familles %}
   <tr>
     <th>{{ famille.personne.name }} :</th>
   </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

i mean show the name of personne and there chidren when ((id-enfant) 'famille table')equale to ((id) in personne table